# SSIS. Make sure job is not running

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I'm using SSIS 2008. I have 2 scheduled jobs that start 2 different packages.
I would like when package 2 starts, it will make sure that package 1 is not still running. If it is, then exit.

Possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure!! You can do following the below steps

1) In `job2`, add first step to check whether `job1` (and in turn, package1) is running or not - using the below script - got from [Check if a SQL Server Agent job is running](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Check-if-a-SQL-Server-75b889b4)

```
IF NOT EXISTS(     
    select 1 
    from msdb.dbo.sysjobs_view job  
    inner join msdb.dbo.sysjobactivity activity on job.job_id = activity.job_id 
    where  
        activity.run_Requested_date is not null  
    and activity.stop_execution_date is null  
    and job.name = @JOB_NAME -- name of job1
)
```

2)The above script will return boolean value, based on which, you can decide to execute the 2nd step of `job2` - which will be - to execute `package2`

Answer (score 3):

Another approach would be to define two steps in SQL JOBs in order which you want to execute the package, then set On Success Action to "Go to the next step" for package1 and set on Success Action to "Quit the job reporting success" on package 2.

package 2 will run only after package 1 completion.